# How do I check that a string contains a date?

Tags: powershell

My script's input parameter is a date or a number. Here's a script that works fine, so you can see what I am trying to do:

```
param($date = (Get-Date))

if ($date -match "^\d+$")
{  
    $date = (Get-Date).AddDays($date)
} 
elseif ($date -as [DateTime]) 
{
    $date = [DateTime]::Parse($date)  
}
else 
{  
    'You entered an invalid date'
    exit 1
}
```

Here's my previous attempt that *does not* work:

```
param($date = (Get-Date))

if ($date -as [DateTime]) 
{
    $date = [DateTime]::Parse($date)  
}
elseif ($date -match "^\d+$")
{  
    $date = (Get-Date).AddDays($date)
} 
else 
{  
    'You entered an invalid date'
    exit 1
}
```

When I input a number, the script breaks at date parsing line. It looks like my "is is date" check returns true when given a number.

Is it a bug? Is it by design?

Comment: It's my first powershell script, so feel free to point out my possible mistakes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can check that a string contains date by using ‘(-as [DateTime])’. The problem in my original script is that I assumed that script input parameters are strings. Apparently, numerical parameter is automatically converted to integer, unless it is typed with quotes. So, I should have written

```
if ([string]$date -as [DateTime])
```

forcing converting possible number back to string, as Keith does in his answer.

Same flaw applies to my integer check. The script fails when given “Oct,3” (without quotes). Does PS create an array here?

Why does parsing fail when check succeeds? Johannes explained that. Expression

```
$date -as [DateTime]
```

instructs PS to convert input to date. Converting number makes sense (date 1 is January 01, 0001), so it does not fail when given a number. Expression

```
[DateTime]::Parse($date)
```

specifically parses a string, so giving it an integer does not make sense and leads to error.

It was wasteful of me to use both, anyway. First, I convert to date in the condition, only to throw away the result. Then, I recreate the result with different syntax. I’m changing that to

```
$date = $date -as [DateTime];
if (!$date)
{  
    'You entered an invalid date'
    exit 1
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: U can just use `-is` directly on the "DateTime" var as in `if($date -is [DateTime])` for a truly Boolean result - but `-as [DateTime]` works there too - on both strings and dates.  Also (in original post), no need to do `[DateTime]::Parse` on a field that's already of type "DateTime".

Comment: how does -as [DateTime] handle null values?  I wish powershell would not assign null to a variable.

Answer (score 11):

You can let the .NET Framework help you with this:

```
function ParseDate([string]$date)
{
    $result = 0
    if (!([DateTime]::TryParse($date, [ref]$result)))
    {
        throw "You entered an invalid date: $date"
     }

    $result
}

ParseDate 'June 51, 2001'
```

Comment: Or you could let PowerShell do _all_ the heavy lifting: just use `[DateTime]$date` to require the parameter to be of type `DateTime`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can cast any integer to a `DateTime`, simply because `DateTime` is just a number behind the scenes.

Every `DateTime` has a `Ticks` property which are 100 ns intervals since 0001-01-01. You can initialize a `DateTime` with those ticks, even though I didn't find a use for it so far.

```
PS> ([datetime]1234).Ticks
1234
```

But that's why you can cast a number to `DateTime` and it works. It's probably just a date very far back in time :-)

So basically, what you're doing now, i. e. checking for a number first, is the proper way to go as the cast to `DateTime` doesn't suffice in helping you determining whether it's a date or a number.

Comment: I prefer this approach to using the [DateTime]::Parse method because this approach has a very nifty side-effect.  Since PowerShell will always try to cast whatever it gets for a parameter to the type it needs, you can call this function with simple strings in any localized datetime format:

i.e. Foo "1:OO PM", Foo "1/1/2012 20:12"

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't follow.  The same works for DateTime parse, it uses the culture of the current thread when parsing the string.  Ultimately, I would venture that the PowerShell conversion winds up at DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse.  I see no reason why they would want to reimplement that code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short alternative:

```
function isDate([string]$strdate)
{
    [boolean]($strdate -as [DateTime])
}
```